# postgis uprade route

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgis

I need to upgrade

- **source**: rhel7-pg-10-postgis-2.4
- **target**: rhel8-pg-14-postgis-3.1

is my assupmtion correct, that I need to go in these steps (using pg_dump/pg_restore to jump between versions)?

1. pg10-gis2.4
2. pg10-gis2.5
3. pg12-gis2.5
4. pg12-gis3.1
5. pg14-gis3.1

or do I even need an additional gis-3.0 between 2.5 > 3.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading via pg_dump/pg_restore is suitable for you, then you can upgrade directly by using pg_dump on pg10-gis2.4 and restore onto pg14-gis3.1.

The process is more complicated if you need to use `pg_upgrade` due to the size of the database.

Comment: are you sure? I allways thought each new postgis comes with new or different functions and it is not unlikely that functions that eixts in 2.5 might not be available or work differentlz on 3.1, so a direct upgrade is doomed to fail.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I carried out many postgresql upgrades, including postgis and other evil spirits. The database itself can be upgraded directly. It's definitely worth reading the changelogs, it may be necessary to change something in the *application* code to reflect changes. But that's another question.

Comment: so then you need thorrow understanding to fix the occuring issues, right? I am lacking that I am afraid. So I guess `pg_upgrade`, `SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade()` and a route as the above would be the means of choice in such a case then.